# CSS file name being referenced in another CSS file?

Tags: css

:)

I've inherited a website, and I'm going through the CSS files to condense them right now. I found a piece of code that is confusing me; not sure if it's intentionally placed in there or not. The code in question is:

```
table{text.css
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

The issue I'm having is with `text.css`. Right now we're using two CSS files named 960.css and text.css, so I assume that that's where the reference is coming from. Is this actually having any effect on the code or is it just a weird artifact of something a previous coder was doing? Haven't been able to find ANYTHING on this topic, so I imagine it's just an accidental coding.

Thanks!

Comment: Is essentially the same declaration somewhere in text.css?  That might be what that artifact was meant to indicate.

Comment: It's not, actually, so... looks like it's just a random addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that will do is prevent the "margin-bottom" declaration from doing anything.  So yes, weird artifact.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't look like it was at all intentional. Thanks! :)